# how to set querystring in Command of Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have made a crystal report in which I pass the database name into querystring. I want to bind that database into crystal report Command. So how is it possible because the report shows the data from multiple database as per selection of user.

I make a webform and use crystal report viewer. I send the database name into querystring.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that you should used data table as data source and used a stored procedure or a query where you will decided which database the data will come from.

check this link that will help

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C